# ANTLR v4 dynamic grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I have this grammar:

```
grammar ProcedureHeaderLanguage ;

@header
{
  package com.company.generated.antlr.atr;
}

fragment DIGIT
  : '0'..'9'
  ;

fragment A
  : [aA]
  ;

fragment B
  : [bB]
  ;

fragment C
  : [cC]
  ;

fragment D
  : [dD]
  ;

fragment E
  : [eE]
  ;

fragment F
  : [fF]
  ;

fragment G
  : [gG]
  ;

fragment H
  : [hH]
  ;

fragment I
  : [iI]
  ;

fragment J
  : [jJ]
  ;

fragment K
  : [kK]
  ;

fragment L
  : [lL]
  ;

fragment M
  : [mM]
  ;

fragment N
  : [nN]
  ;

fragment O
  : [oO]
  ;

fragment P
  : [pP]
  ;

fragment Q
  : [qQ]
  ;

fragment R
  : [rR]
  ;

fragment S
  : [sS]
  ;

fragment T
  : [tT]
  ;

fragment U
  : [uU]
  ;

fragment V
  : [vV]
  ;

fragment W
  : [wW]
  ;

fragment X
  : [xX]
  ;

fragment Y
  : [yY]
  ;

fragment Z
  : [zZ]
  ;

fragment DIGIT_PAIR
  : DIGIT DIGIT
  ;

fragment ALPHA
  : 'a'..'z'
  | 'A'..'Z'
  ;

SEMICOLON
  : ';'
  ;

HYPHEN
  : '-'
  ;

PROCEDURE_IDENTIFIER
  : P R O C E D U R E
  ;

COMMA
  : ','
  ;

LEFT_PARENTHESIS
  : '('
  ;

RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
  : ')'
  ;

dataField
  : IDENTIFIER
  ;

nameField
  : dataField
  ;

parameterNameField
  : dataField
  ;

dataTypeField
  : dataField
  ;

IN
  : I N
  ;

WS
  : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> skip
  ;

IDENTIFIER
  : (ALPHA | '_') (ALPHA | DIGIT | '_')*
  ;

COMMENT
  : HYPHEN HYPHEN
  ;

parameterPair
  : parameterNameField IN dataTypeField
  ;

procedureName
  : PROCEDURE_IDENTIFIER nameField
  ;

procedureParameter
  : LEFT_PARENTHESIS parameterPair (COMMA parameterPair)* RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
  ;

procedure
  : procedureName procedureParameter SEMICOLON
  ;

procedures
  : procedure (procedure)*
  ;
```

which is able to parse the following example:

```
sorten_COBB_SEK in number,
sorten_COBB_VORG in number,
```

However the parsing files will not only contain such data.
It will also store some informations which are optional and not mandatory.
I know I could simply tell them to be optional with `?` but it's not that simple.

I additionally have this example:

```
sorten_FEUCHTE_MIN in number,
sorten_FEUCHTE_MAX in number,
sorten_FEUCHTE_SPERR in number,
sorten_LEIMUNG in varchar2, -- J or N
sorten_BEMERKUNG in varchar2
```

where `-- J or N` is in association with the entry sorten_LEIMUNG and I want to get that information for that entry. The problem is that the delimitier COMMA is before the comment which I want to parse.

so some grammar like this will not work:

```
parameterPair
  : parameterNameField IN dataTypeField COMMA? COMMENT? dataField?
  ;

procedureParameter
  : LEFT_PARENTHESIS parameterPair (parameterPair)* RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
  ;
```

How can I achieve the goal to also register the comment for the same entry (same line)?

**EDIT:** as said the above grammar will parse the first example correctly. However the second one will be broken. It will detect `or` as new `parameterName`.
With the second grammar change I am able to parse `-- J` while the rest will be detected as a new parameterName.

How can I tell antlr to parse how I wish, or is this a limitation where I am better of telling the user to not use spaces in his comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I just started using ANTLR I don't know if this is the best solution but with the grammar rule:

```
SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT
  : '--' (.)*? '\r'? '\n'
  ;

parameterPair
  : parameterNameField IN dataTypeField COMMA? SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT?
  ;
```

I am then able to do this in a custom visitor:

```
/**
     * Filters out the needed informations of the antlr parser context and 
     * creates the POJO {@link SqlParameter} with it.
     *
     * @param parameterPair the parameter pair
     * @return the sql parameter
     */
    private SqlParameter createParameter( ParameterPairContext parameterPair )
    {
      final String parameterName = parameterPair.parameterNameField().getText();
      final String dataType = parameterPair.dataTypeField().getText();
      Optional<String> comment = Optional.empty();
      if ( parameterPair.SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT() != null )
      {
        comment = Optional.ofNullable( parameterPair.SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT().getText().trim() );
      }

      return new SqlParameter( parameterName, dataType, comment );
    }
```

Which is not really practical in all cases but should do the trick for now. logging it out will result in what I needed:

```
StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
log.append( "Parameter: " );
log.append( parameter.getParameterName() );
log.append( " with type: " );
log.append( parameter.getParameterType() );
parameter.getComment().ifPresent( comment -> log.append( " with comment: " ).append( comment ) );
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Parameter: sorten_FEUCHTE_SPERR with type: number
Parameter: sorten_LEIMUNG with type: varchar2 with comment: -- J or N
Parameter: sorten_BEMERKUNG with type: varchar2
```

Comment: Check if that works also when the single line comment is the last input token without a trailing new line (which is what my EOF token above is addressing).

Comment: But as I commented the EOF is a not valid rule reference. I can't compile when I use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without your whole grammar I cannot do real testing, but I'll try to make a suggestion for you.  Since your comment identifier `--` must be consecutive, I'd code that rule as:

```
TEXT: ALPHA | DIGIT;
TEXTS : TEXT*;

COMMENT
  : '--' TEXTS
  ;
```

Something like that to ensure that your `--` comment + mixed text gets lexed as a comment.

Comment: I will update the grammar tomorrow once I'm at my workplace again.

Comment: I edited my Question with the complete grammar and additional things I tried now.

Comment: There's no difference for `--` vs `HYPHEN HYPHEN` in a lexer rule.

Answer (score 0):

Your `COMMENT` rule is incomplete. It contains only the comment introducer, but nothing that should match the rest of the line. A typical approach is:

```
SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT: '--' ~([\r\n] | EOF)*;
```

Comment: If i try it I will get the gradle error message: `error(134): ProcedureHeaderLanguage.g4:150:20: rule reference EOF is not currently supported in a set`. However removing the EOF will make it work but then I am not able to retrieve the comment text. It is essential that I can access the text in an visitor.